# Get sql text of a UDT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

When creating a function or a trigger, you can find its creation command in `sys.sql_modules`

But what i cannot seem to find is the same for UDTs.

When I create a type like this

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.UserIds AS TABLE (value int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

it doesnt show up in `sys.sql_modules`.

The only information I can find is from sys.types

```
select * from sys.types where is_user_defined = 1
```

but there is no SQL statement. So where do i find it?

Comment: You could get info from metadata. I will provide sample

Comment: @G.SAbhaypal Who says anything about `sys.objects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get info about table type and columns from metadata:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.UserIds AS TABLE (value int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

--
DECLARE @name SYSNAME = 'UserIds';

SELECT  sch = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)
     ,t.name
     ,type     = TYPE_NAME(t.user_type_id)
     ,c.name
     ,col_type = TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id)
     ,c.is_nullable
     --.... more info about max_length (if text) and so on
FROM sys.table_types t
JOIN sys.columns c
  ON t.type_table_object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = @name;
```

Based on that info you could recreate DDL statement.

**EDIT:**

If you want to script it the easiest way is to use SSMS.
`Right-click` -> `Script object as` (same for simple types).

[image]

Comment: That's not enough because TYPE definition can include indexes if someone declare the table with PK or unique

Comment: @sepupic `LEFT JOIN` to `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns` should resolve it

Comment: Types dont necessarily need to be tables, but i guess its the best information i can get here. So i will accept this as an answer sooner or later, if noone else has any better solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so simple to get a type definition, you can prove it to yourself ly launching Profiler and asking SSMS to generate a script as CREATE for your type.

Here is what I've got:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id) AS [Schema],
tt.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
WHERE
(tt.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'YourType',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
clmns.column_id AS [ID],
clmns.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id
WHERE
(tt.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)
ORDER BY
[ID] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'YourType',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
p.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p ON p.major_id=tt.user_type_id AND p.minor_id=clmns.column_id AND p.class=8
WHERE
(clmns.name=@_msparam_0)and((tt.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_2))
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'id_banca',@_msparam_1=N'YourType',@_msparam_2=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
p.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p ON p.major_id=tt.user_type_id AND p.minor_id=0 AND p.class=6
WHERE
(tt.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'YourType',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
cstr.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.check_constraints AS cstr ON cstr.parent_object_id=tt.type_table_object_id
WHERE
(tt.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'YourType',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
ISNULL(s1tt.name, N'''') AS [Owner],
CAST(case when tt.principal_id is null then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsSchemaOwned],
tt.name AS [Name],
tt.type_table_object_id AS [ID],
SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id) AS [Schema],
obj.create_date AS [CreateDate],
obj.modify_date AS [DateLastModified],
tt.max_length AS [MaxLength],
tt.is_nullable AS [Nullable],
ISNULL(tt.collation_name, N'''') AS [Collation],
CAST(case when tt.is_user_defined = 1 then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsUserDefined]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS s1tt ON s1tt.principal_id = ISNULL(tt.principal_id, (TYPEPROPERTY(QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(tt.name), ''OwnerId'')))
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON obj.object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
WHERE
(tt.name=@_msparam_0 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_1)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'YourType',@_msparam_1=N'dbo'


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
clmns.name AS [Name],
clmns.column_id AS [ID],
clmns.is_nullable AS [Nullable],
clmns.is_computed AS [Computed],
CAST(ISNULL(cik.index_column_id, 0) AS bit) AS [InPrimaryKey],
clmns.is_ansi_padded AS [AnsiPaddingStatus],
CAST(clmns.is_rowguidcol AS bit) AS [RowGuidCol],
CAST(ISNULL(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N''IsDeterministic''),0) AS bit) AS [IsDeterministic],
CAST(ISNULL(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N''IsPrecise''),0) AS bit) AS [IsPrecise],
CAST(ISNULL(cc.is_persisted, 0) AS bit) AS [IsPersisted],
ISNULL(clmns.collation_name, N'''') AS [Collation],
CAST(ISNULL((select TOP 1 1 from sys.foreign_key_columns AS colfk where colfk.parent_column_id = clmns.column_id and colfk.parent_object_id = clmns.object_id), 0) AS bit) AS [IsForeignKey],
clmns.is_identity AS [Identity],
CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value,0) AS bigint) AS [IdentitySeed],
CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value,0) AS bigint) AS [IdentityIncrement],
(case when clmns.default_object_id = 0 then N'''' when d.parent_object_id > 0 then N'''' else d.name end) AS [Default],
(case when clmns.default_object_id = 0 then N'''' when d.parent_object_id > 0 then N'''' else schema_name(d.schema_id) end) AS [DefaultSchema],
(case when clmns.rule_object_id = 0 then N'''' else r.name end) AS [Rule],
(case when clmns.rule_object_id = 0 then N'''' else schema_name(r.schema_id) end) AS [RuleSchema],
ISNULL(ic.is_not_for_replication, 0) AS [NotForReplication],
CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N''IsFulltextIndexed'') AS bit) AS [IsFullTextIndexed],
CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(clmns.object_id, clmns.name, N''StatisticalSemantics'') AS int) AS [StatisticalSemantics],
CAST(clmns.is_filestream AS bit) AS [IsFileStream],
CAST(clmns.is_sparse AS bit) AS [IsSparse],
CAST(clmns.is_column_set AS bit) AS [IsColumnSet],
usrt.name AS [DataType],
s1clmns.name AS [DataTypeSchema],
ISNULL(baset.name, N'''') AS [SystemType],
CAST(CASE WHEN baset.name IN (N''nchar'', N''nvarchar'') AND clmns.max_length <> -1 THEN clmns.max_length/2 ELSE clmns.max_length END AS int) AS [Length],
CAST(clmns.precision AS int) AS [NumericPrecision],
CAST(clmns.scale AS int) AS [NumericScale],
ISNULL(xscclmns.name, N'''') AS [XmlSchemaNamespace],
ISNULL(s2clmns.name, N'''') AS [XmlSchemaNamespaceSchema],
ISNULL( (case clmns.is_xml_document when 1 then 2 else 1 end), 0) AS [XmlDocumentConstraint],
CASE WHEN usrt.is_table_type = 1 THEN N''structured'' ELSE N'''' END AS [UserType]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS ik ON ik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 1=ik.is_primary_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns AS cik ON cik.index_id = ik.index_id and cik.column_id = clmns.column_id and cik.object_id = clmns.object_id and 0 = cik.is_included_column
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.computed_columns AS cc ON cc.object_id = clmns.object_id and cc.column_id = clmns.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = clmns.object_id and ic.column_id = clmns.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS d ON d.object_id = clmns.default_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS r ON r.object_id = clmns.rule_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS usrt ON usrt.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas AS s1clmns ON s1clmns.schema_id = usrt.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS baset ON (baset.user_type_id = clmns.system_type_id and baset.user_type_id = baset.system_type_id) or ((baset.system_type_id = clmns.system_type_id) and (baset.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id) and (baset.is_user_defined = 0) and (baset.is_assembly_type = 1)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_schema_collections AS xscclmns ON xscclmns.xml_collection_id = clmns.xml_collection_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas AS s2clmns ON s2clmns.schema_id = xscclmns.schema_id
WHERE
(clmns.name=@_msparam_0)and((tt.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_2))',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'id_banca',@_msparam_1=N'YourType',@_msparam_2=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
cstr.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints AS cstr ON cstr.object_id=clmns.default_object_id
WHERE
(clmns.name=@_msparam_0)and((tt.name=@_msparam_1 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_2))
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'id_banca',@_msparam_1=N'YourType',@_msparam_2=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
i.name AS [Name],
CAST(i.index_id AS int) AS [ID],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(i.object_id,N''IsMSShipped'') AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
ISNULL(s.no_recompute,0) AS [NoAutomaticRecomputation],
i.fill_factor AS [FillFactor],
CAST(CASE i.index_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsClustered],
i.is_primary_key + 2*i.is_unique_constraint AS [IndexKeyType],
i.is_unique AS [IsUnique],
i.ignore_dup_key AS [IgnoreDuplicateKeys],
~i.allow_row_locks AS [DisallowRowLocks],
~i.allow_page_locks AS [DisallowPageLocks],
CAST(ISNULL(INDEXPROPERTY(i.object_id, i.name, N''IsPadIndex''), 0) AS bit) AS [PadIndex],
i.is_disabled AS [IsDisabled],
CAST(ISNULL(k.is_system_named, 0) AS bit) AS [IsSystemNamed],
CAST(INDEXPROPERTY(i.object_id,i.name,N''IsFulltextKey'') AS bit) AS [IsFullTextKey],
CAST(case when i.type=3 then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsXmlIndex],
case UPPER(ISNULL(xi.secondary_type,'''')) when ''P'' then 1 when ''V'' then 2 when ''R'' then 3 else 0 end AS [SecondaryXmlIndexType],
ISNULL(xi2.name, N'''') AS [ParentXmlIndex],
CAST(ISNULL(spi.spatial_index_type,0) AS tinyint) AS [SpatialIndexType],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_xmin,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxXMin],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_ymin,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxYMin],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_xmax,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxXMax],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_ymax,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxYMax],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_1_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level1Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_2_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level2Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_3_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level3Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_4_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level4Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.cells_per_object,0) AS int) AS [CellsPerObject],
CAST(case when i.type=4 then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsSpatialIndex],
i.has_filter AS [HasFilter],
ISNULL(i.filter_definition, N'''') AS [FilterDefinition],
CASE WHEN ''FG''=dsi.type THEN dsi.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileGroup],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dsi.type THEN dsi.name ELSE N'''' END AS [PartitionScheme],
CAST(CASE WHEN ''PS''=dsi.type THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsPartitioned],
CASE WHEN ''FD''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamFileGroup],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamPartitionScheme],
CAST(CASE WHEN filetableobj.object_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS [IsFileTableDefined],
CAST(
          CASE i.type WHEN 1 THEN 0 WHEN 4 THEN 4
                      WHEN 3 THEN CASE xi.xml_index_type WHEN 0 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 2 THEN 7 WHEN 3 THEN 8 END
                      WHEN 4 THEN 4 WHEN 6 THEN 5 ELSE 1 END
        AS tinyint) AS [IndexType],

        ISNULL(indexedpaths.name, N'''')
       AS [IndexedXmlPathName]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.index_id > @_msparam_0 and i.is_hypothetical = @_msparam_1) AND (i.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.stats AS s ON s.stats_id = i.index_id AND s.object_id = i.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.key_constraints AS k ON k.parent_object_id = i.object_id AND k.unique_index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_indexes AS xi ON xi.object_id = i.object_id AND xi.index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_indexes AS xi2 ON xi2.object_id = xi.object_id AND xi2.index_id = xi.using_xml_index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.spatial_indexes AS spi ON i.object_id = spi.object_id and i.index_id = spi.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.spatial_index_tessellations as si ON i.object_id = si.object_id and i.index_id = si.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dsi ON dsi.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dstbl ON dstbl.data_space_id = t.Filestream_data_space_id and (i.index_id < 2 or (i.type = 7 and i.index_id < 3))
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.filetable_system_defined_objects AS filetableobj ON i.object_id = filetableobj.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.selective_xml_index_paths AS indexedpaths ON xi.object_id = indexedpaths.object_id AND xi.using_xml_index_id = indexedpaths.index_id AND xi.path_id = indexedpaths.path_id
WHERE
(i.name=@_msparam_2)and((tt.name=@_msparam_3 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_4))',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_4 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'0',@_msparam_1=N'0',@_msparam_2=N'PK__TT_id_ba__70BD165044265C38',@_msparam_3=N'YourType',@_msparam_4=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
(case ic.key_ordinal when 0 then ic.index_column_id else ic.key_ordinal end) AS [ID],
clmns.name AS [Name]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.index_id > @_msparam_0 and i.is_hypothetical = @_msparam_1) AND (i.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON (ic.column_id > 0 and (ic.key_ordinal > 0 or ic.partition_ordinal = 0 or ic.is_included_column != 0)) AND (ic.index_id=CAST(i.index_id AS int) AND ic.object_id=i.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id = ic.object_id and clmns.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE
(i.name=@_msparam_2)and((tt.name=@_msparam_3 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_4))
ORDER BY
[ID] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_4 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'0',@_msparam_1=N'0',@_msparam_2=N'PK__TT_id_ba__70BD165044265C38',@_msparam_3=N'YourType',@_msparam_4=N'dbo'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
clmns.name AS [Name],
(case ic.key_ordinal when 0 then ic.index_column_id else ic.key_ordinal end) AS [ID],
CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(ic.object_id, clmns.name, N''IsComputed'') AS bit) AS [IsComputed],
ic.is_descending_key AS [Descending],
ic.is_included_column AS [IsIncluded]
FROM
sys.table_types AS tt
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS stt ON stt.schema_id = tt.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.index_id > @_msparam_0 and i.is_hypothetical = @_msparam_1) AND (i.object_id=tt.type_table_object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON (ic.column_id > 0 and (ic.key_ordinal > 0 or ic.partition_ordinal = 0 or ic.is_included_column != 0)) AND (ic.index_id=CAST(i.index_id AS int) AND ic.object_id=i.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id = ic.object_id and clmns.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE
(clmns.name=@_msparam_2)and((i.name=@_msparam_3)and((tt.name=@_msparam_4 and SCHEMA_NAME(tt.schema_id)=@_msparam_5)))',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_4 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_5 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'0',@_msparam_1=N'0',@_msparam_2=N'id_banca',@_msparam_3=N'PK__TT_id_ba__70BD165044265C38',@_msparam_4=N'YourType',@_msparam_5=N'dbo'
```

This is to give you an idea how complex it is

Answer (score 0):

Types and UDTs don't appear in either sys.objects or sys.sql_modules, simply because they're not modules but types.

for getting the script of a UDT you gotta join sys.types with sys.schemas, on schema_id field. and still you need to do some parsing and conversion i suppose.